# Update state on scroll react hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to be able to update my state as the user scrolls.

This is an approximation of what I have:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [scrollNumber, updateScrollNumber] = useState(0);
  const onScroll = () => updateScrollNumber(scrollNumber + 12);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener('scroll', (event) => onScroll())
  },[])
  return (
    <div onScroll={onScroll} className="App" style={{ height: 200000 }}>
      {console.log({ scrollNumber })}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Why does `scrollNumber` not update?

Here is a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-shirley-2wkwm?file=/src/App.js:0-447).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is you are adding onScroll event to a div. It will be called if you scroll inside the div. But in reality, you are scrolling in the window. Therefore you need to attach an event listener on window scroll. To do that you can use useEffect hook like this.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [scrollNumber, updateScrollNumber] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(() => {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
      return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  }, [scrollNumber]);

  const onScroll = () => {
    console.log("updating the scrollNumber");
    updateScrollNumber(scrollNumber + 12);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{ height: 200000 }}>
      {console.log({ scrollNumber })}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For more reading on scroll event you can look [here](https://javascript.info/onscroll).

Comment: it updates once and doesn't continue to update after that. any idea why?

Comment: It was happening because everytime the state value changed the onScroll method changed to a new instance. But in useEffect we are using the first version of the onScroll method. That is why we needed to add the dependency in the useEffect. So that everytime our state changes we are using the new version of onScroll.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [scrollNumber, updateScrollNumber] = useState(0);
  const onScroll = () => updateScrollNumber((prevScroll) => prevScroll + 12);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div onScroll={onScroll} className="App" style={{ height: 200000 }}>
      {console.log({ scrollNumber })}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have used onSroll in your div. If you want to be able to do it inside div; set its property overflow to scroll. If you want it to work on window scroll; add an eventListener.

This should work:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [scrollNumber, updateScrollNumber] = useState(0);
  const onScroll = () => updateScrollNumber(scrollNumber + 12);
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll)
    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll)
  })

  return (
    <div
      onScroll={onScroll}
      className="App"
      style={{ height: 200000}}
    >
      {console.log({ scrollNumber })}
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```